# Angular: disable MatButton if MatMenu hasn't MatMenuItem

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

I have a complex `MatMenu` with more `MatMenuItem`. Each `MatMenuItem`'s visibility is based on a condition. The trigger button is disabled if all possible condition are false, eg.:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [disable]="!condition1 && !condition2 && !condition3 && !conditionN">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="condition1">Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="condition2">Item 2</button>
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="condition3">Item 3</button>
  ...
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="conditionN">Item N</button>
</mat-menu>
```

There are a simple way for check if a `MatMenu` has at least one `MatMenuItem` and disable the trigger button if no one `MatMenuItem` are available?

Comment: [disabled]="!menu._allItems?.length", no extra code solution using currently existing references as _allItems isn't private it can be referenced, but note that all items includes submenus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue with `items`

As mentioned in previous answer, one potential solution could be to use `items` of exported `matMenu`.

But we will have 2 issues :

- `items` property is [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e3f15856799ba5bb368539f88e46f506fc385d8b/src/material/menu/menu.ts#L186), and could be removed soon.

```js
/**
 * List of the items inside of a menu.
 * @deprecated
 * @breaking-change 8.0.0
 */
items: QueryList<MatMenuItem>;
```

- set `disabled` property with `matMenu.items.length` will throw a NG0100 error if we are in default change detection strategy (not in OnPush), because change detection process is not finished.

#### Potential solution

To solve this, we can create a reusable directive, which will query `MatMenuItem` of a `MatMenu`, and then fire an event with the current status of menu : `true` if at least one option, `false` if not.

menu-toggled.directive.ts:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-menu',
})
export class MenuToggledDirective implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
  _destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  @ContentChildren(MatMenuItem, { descendants: true })
  _items!: QueryList<MatMenuItem>;

  @Output()
  menuToggled = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this._items.changes
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroyed$),
        startWith(0),
        map((_) => this._items.length > 0)
      )
      .subscribe(this.menuToggled);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroyed$.next();
    this._destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

Usage in app.component.html :

```html
<button #button mat-stroked-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
  Menu
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" (menuToggled)="button.disabled = !$event">
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="flag">Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="false">Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: I love this solution :)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist improving your solution (great inspiration)

Answer (score 2):

I love the solution proposed by Thierry Falvo, so I try to improve. If we has a directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-menu',
  exportAs:'matMenuExtend' //<--see the exportAs
})
export class MenuToggledDirective implements AfterContentInit{

  //in constructor inject as public the matMenu
  constructor(public menu:MatMenu){}

  @ContentChildren(MatMenuItem, { descendants: true })
  _items!: QueryList<MatMenuItem>;

  allDisabled$:any

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {

    //create an observable "allDisabled$"
    this.allDisabled$ = 
      this._items.changes.pipe(
        startWith(0),
        delay(0),     //<--it's necessary this delay(0)
        map((_) => this._items.length == 0),
      )
  }
}
```

We can write some like

```
<!--see that the mat-meu-trigger-for is about "menu.menu"
    the MatMenu injected in our directive -->

<button #button mat-stroked-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu.menu"
         [disabled]="menu.allDisabled$|async">
Menu
</button>

<!--now our referenceVariable is of type MenuToggledDirective (see
    that indicate the "exportAs" of the directive)-->

<mat-menu #menu="matMenuExtend">

    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="flag">Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="false">Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aimdeo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-toggle.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial.module.ts)

Comment: Good catch for `delay(0)`, it ensures new event is emitted in a new macrotask (in event loop), so no issue with change detection cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read `items.length` property of `menu` something like

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [disable]="!menu?.items?.length">Menu</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpjtvy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-icons-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-icons-example.ts)

[image]

Comment: You will encounter 2 issues with this solution. The minor issue is that `items` property is marked as deprecated. The major one is in default change detection strategy, a NG0100 error will throw, because `[disabled]` property is updated during change detection process. (Maybe it's why this `items` property is marked as deprecated, to avoid this kind of usage...)

Answer (score 0):

**Update** please check the Thierry Falvo's answer

<strike>I feel that the best bet is instead using condition1,condition2,...</strike> You can use an array disabled or an array of object to create your mat-menu (*)

```
menus=[{title:'item 1',disabled:false,action:1},
      {title:'item 2',disabled:false,action:2},
      {title:'item 2',disabled:false,action:3}
       ....
     ]

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [disable]="disableMenu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menus" 
  <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="!menu.disabled" 
         (click)="doSomething(menu.action)">
        {{menu.title}}
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

You can use a getter like

```
get disableMenu()
{
   return this.menus.find(x=>!x.disabled)?false:true
}
```

Or instead of use a getter use one variable and when you any object of the array menus equal the variable to `this.menus.find(x=>!x.disabled)?false:true`

<strike>(*) the main problem I see in others approaches are that really the "menu" is in an cdk-overlay-container layer and it's difficult check it</strike>

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpjtvy-f4you1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-icons-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-icons-example.html)